# How to pass data to a jQuery dialog button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I created a php/javaScript automatisation of our form creation. Thus, when a dialog is created the button are added dynamicly and correctly, but I cannot access the JSON object in the function trigged on the click of the button.

Here is a exemple (The alert does not work, is not display):

```
aButtons[oGeneratedFormButtons[x].label] = function(){ alert(oGeneratedFormButtons[i].label); });
```

Can I pass data to the function or is there a way to know which button has been clicked.

Here is a simple sample : http://jsfiddle.net/DavidLaberge/h4Cgp/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using closure like this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < JSON.length; x++) {
    aButtons[JSON[x].label] = (function() {
        var i = x;
        return function() {
            alert(i);
            alert(JSON[i].label);
        }
    })();
}
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/h4Cgp/14/).

Comment: it works, but would you might to explain a bit. I'm not sure to undestand why. :(

Comment: @David, my example is using closure feature of javascript. You can find needed info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inside and the solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the problem is not that you are using a different variable (i instead of x) inside the function? Because oGeneratedFormButtons[x].label should be accessible inside the function if it's accessible outside it.

```
aButtons[oGeneratedFormButtons[x].label] = function(){ alert(oGeneratedFormButtons[x].label); });
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I forgot to change it after testing different ways that I could think about.

Comment: @David the alerto doesn't work means that it alerts undefined or that there is no alert?You should also post the rest of your code.

Comment: @David post your code here and if you can also on jsfiddle.net so we can help you better